# Android cursor.getInt

Tags: android

I got a problem with a function.
I've got a function to find the max(id) of a table and it works but with another table it doesn't work.
First, my database :

```
`//MAGASIN
public static final String MAGASIN_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+ MAGASIN_TABLE_NAME + " ("+
            MAGASIN_KEY + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            MAGASIN_NOM + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MAGASIN_ADRESSE + " TEXT);";`
```

`

```
//LISTE`

    public static final String LISTE_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+ LISTE_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            LISTE_KEY + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            LISTE_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+
            LISTE_DATE_CREATION + " TEXT, "+
            LISTE_DATE_LAST_MODIFICATION + " TEXT, "+
            LISTE_IS_FINAL + " INTEGER, " +
            LISTE_NUM_MAGASIN + " INTEGER, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY("+ LISTE_NUM_MAGASIN +") REFERENCES MAGASIN("+ MAGASIN_KEY +"));";
```

After that my first function which works :

```
 public int selectMaxNumMagasin()
{
    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select numMagasin as _id from magasin order by _id desc limit 1",null);
    int max;
    if (cursor == null)
    {
        max = 1;
        return max;
    }
    else
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        max = cursor.getInt(0) + 1;
        cursor.close();
        return max;
    }
}
```

And finally the last one which doesn't works

`

```
public int selectMaxNumListe()
    {
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select numListe as _id from liste order by _id desc limit 1",null);
        int max;
        if (cursor == null)
        {
            max = 1;
            return max;
        }
        else
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            max = cursor.getInt(0);
            max += 1;
            cursor.close();
            return max;
        }
    }`
```

I've done some tests it seems to be the

> cursor.getInt(0);

that got stuck.

Hope someone will find a solution, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rawQuery()` always returns a valid `Cursor`, or throws an exception. Checking for `null` cursor is not a way to check whether there are results.

Instead, check the result value of `moveToFirst()` to check for non-empty cursor.

Also note that you can do your work entirely in SQL, e.g. `SELECT MAX(columnname)+1 FROM tablename`.

Answer (score 0):

you return always 2 in your second function, try to return max intead of 2

Comment: It was to test this function, it was max instead of 2 :)

Comment: so try to check if(cursor.moveToFirst()) { //do something} as answered on @laalto post